# Spring Boot Security Jwt Authentication Fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I work on a web application which is based on Spring Boot and Angular. The application fails when users are logged in the client side. I used this link https://github.com/bezkoder/angular-11-spring-boot-jwt-authentication as tutorial reference.I get the following errors:

```
Client-> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
Server -> AuthEntryPointJwt   : Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

**AuthEntryPointJwt.java**

```
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

**AuthTokenFilter.java**

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);
    public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                if (!username.isEmpty()) {
                    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                } else {
                    logger.error("Username is null");
                }
            }else {
                logger.error("jwt is null");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**JwtUtils.java**

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${jwtExpirationMs}")
    private String jwtExpirationMs;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + Integer.valueOf(jwtExpirationMs)))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    
    public static final String[] AUTHENTICATED_URLS = { "/app/user/**", "/app/item/**"};
    public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/app/login" ;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;


    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthEntryPointJwt authenticationEntryPointJwt() {
        return new AuthEntryPointJwt();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()      .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(AUTHENTICATED_URLS ).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);   
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I've seen this error when security is not enabled on the api endpoint. You can try adding this property to your application.properties: `management.security.enabled=false` and see if that resolves the error.

Comment: You are aware that all code you have here is not needed as spring security already has built in support for handling jwts. There is an entire chapter in the spring security docs

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when security is not enabled on the api endpoint.

You can try adding this property to your *application.properties* and see if that resolves the error:

```
management.security.enabled=false
```